# workflow marked as start on update

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-workflow, nintex-workflow

I have a nintex workflow set to fire when an item is modified. If the workflow modifies an item, will it trigger the same workflow again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once upon a time, yes; however, this was a bug. If you are running on the latest version, no.

At least, this is true of Nintex Workflow 2007 on our MOSS 2007 SP2 farm using the Set Field activity.

Answer (score 0):

With SP 2010, Nintex does not offer the ability to disable event firing (like visual studio does).  Therefore, starting a wf when an item is maintained is not a good option if the wf updates the item.  It will trigger a loop.